# Getting tag based on ID of element inside shadowroot

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, lit

I am having the below html that I render in a lit component:

```
render() {
    return html`
          <div class="table">
            <div id="col">
              <p>testing this component</p>
</div>
</div>`
```

through the below constructor I'm calling a resize handler:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._handleResize);
  }
```

the handleresize method is as below:

```
private _handleResize = () =>{
  var some_id = document.getElementById('col');
  var tag = some_id.tagName; ///some_id is coming out as null
}
```

I am trying to get the tag of 'col' ID and it's throwing me null. Can someone tell what is the mistake here?

Comment: The shadowRoot is encapsulated. You need to get the element from there: `this.shadowRoot?.getElementById('col');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying for the element, you should use a reference:

[Referencing rendered DOM](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#ref)

```
import {ref} from 'lit/directives/ref.js';

[...]

  colRef = createRef();

[...]

  render() {
    return html`
      <div class="table">
        <div id="col" ${ref(this.colRef)}>
          <p>testing this component</p>
        </div>
      </div>`
  }

  private _handleResize = () =>{
    const col = this.colRef.value!;
    const tag = col.tagName;
  }
```

I also suggest to using `const` and `let` instead of var.
Furthermore you should probably use `ResizeObserver` instead of an eventlistener on `window`.
Also don't forget to unregister your eventlisteners.